# C# - Zero Based String error

Tags: c#, string, zero

It comes up with this error when I try to login.

Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string name = textBox1.Text;
        string.Format ("{0} {1}", "Best", "Regards");

        if (textBox1.Text == "Ryan" && textBox2.Text == "password")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Welcome {1}" ));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry you were right. I flagged it myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`string.Format("Welcome {1}" )`

needs an argument

`string.Format("Welcome {0}", textBox1.Text )`

Comment: this stopped the error. but what is the point in have it if it doesnt showing up the text I told it {0} which is "best".

Or have I misunderstood what this completely does?

Comment: ? please help as Im pretty confused now

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what the 0 does, the zero is a reference to an argument that is found after the comma, here is a pretty good example

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Formatting_Strings_in_C_Sharp

Comment: it is only "best" for your first `string format`

Answer (score 5):

The error is thrown in this line:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Welcome {1}" ));
```

because you have used the placeholder `{1}` but havn't provided an argument to the `string.Format` function. Beside that you have not started with the index 0.

You have to provide an argument and start with the index 0:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Welcome {0}", textBox1.Text));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the following:

```
string.Format("Welcome {0}", "some value here");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Welcome {0}", "some text"));
```